# Accessing inner text of a div returning empty string

Tags: html, ruby, dom, watir

I'm trying to extract the answer text on the following webpage. I opened up the DOM inspector and got the class of the text as `"answer_content"`. I've defined a method that looks like:

```
def get_answer()
  @browser.div(:class, "answer_content")
end 

puts page.get_answer.text
```

However, this prints an empty spring. Did I identify the wrong element? When I look at it in the DOM inspector, there does seem to be nothing in between the `div`s.

Comment: Show us the HTML that you are working against.

Comment: Answer text?  Is this homework?  Also you need to include more HTML as has been suggested.  With the current details it sounds like the answer must be "".

Comment: Looks to me that there are more than one div elements with that class. This will tell you if my guess was correct:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that there are more than one `div` elements with that `class`. This will tell you if my guess was correct:

```
@browser.divs(:class, "answer_content").size
```

Comment: was going to suggest same check, but @Zeljko beat me to it.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden: The fastest keyboard in Texas. :)